# Antlr3: building parse tree for qualified names

Tags: java, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, antlr3, parse-tree

I couldn't find a question/answer that comes close to helping with my issue. Therefore, I am posting this question here.

I am trying to build a parse tree for qualified names. The below example shows an example.

E.g.,

1. foo_boo.aaa.ccc1_c [image]

Here I have dot separated words. I am using antlr3 and below is my grammer.

```
parse
    :  expr
    ;


list_expr : <I removed the grammar here>
SimpleType : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
           ;

QualifiedType : SimpleType | SimpleType ('\.' SimpleType)+;


expr : list_expr
    | QualifiedType
    | union_expr;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

Here, `SympleType` represents grammar for a word. My requirement is to build the grammar for the `QualifiedType`. The current grammar given in above is not working as expected (`QualifiedType : SimpleType | SimpleType ('\.'SimpleType)+;`). **How to write correct grammar for Qualified names (Dot separated words)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `QualifiedType` a parser rule instead of a lexer rule:

```
qualifiedType : SimpleType ('.' SimpleType)*;
```

Also, `'\.'` does not need an escape: `'.'` is OK.

### EDIT

You'll have to set [the output to `AST` and apply some tree rewrite rules](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687090/Tree+construction) to make it work properly. Here's a quick demo:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  Root;
  QualifiedName;
}

parse
 : qualifiedType EOF -> ^(Root qualifiedType)
 ;

qualifiedType
 : SimpleType ('.' SimpleType)* -> ^(QualifiedName SimpleType+)
 ;

SimpleType
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')*
 ;
```

And if you now run the code:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTree;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.DOTTreeGenerator;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("foo_boo.aaa.ccc1_c"));
        TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
        DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
        StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

you'll get some [DOT output](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20%7B%0A%0A%09ordering%3Dout%3B%0A%09ranksep%3D.4%3B%0A%09bgcolor%3D%22lightgrey%22%3B%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dbox%2C%20fixedsize%3Dfalse%2C%20fontsize%3D12%2C%20fontname%3D%22Helvetica-bold%22%2C%20fontcolor%3D%22blue%22%0A%09%09width%3D.25%2C%20height%3D.25%2C%20color%3D%22black%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22white%22%2C%20style%3D%22filled%2C%20solid%2C%20bold%22%5D%3B%0A%09edge%20%5Barrowsize%3D.5%2C%20color%3D%22black%22%2C%20style%3D%22bold%22%5D%0A%0A%20%20n0%20%5Blabel%3D%22Root%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20n1%20%5Blabel%3D%22QualifiedName%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20n1%20%5Blabel%3D%22QualifiedName%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20n2%20%5Blabel%3D%22foo_boo%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20n3%20%5Blabel%3D%22aaa%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20n4%20%5Blabel%3D%22ccc1_c%22%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20n0%20-%3E%20n1%20%2F%2F%20%22Root%22%20-%3E%20%22QualifiedName%22%0A%20%20n1%20-%3E%20n2%20%2F%2F%20%22QualifiedName%22%20-%3E%20%22foo_boo%22%0A%20%20n1%20-%3E%20n3%20%2F%2F%20%22QualifiedName%22%20-%3E%20%22aaa%22%0A%20%20n1%20-%3E%20n4%20%2F%2F%20%22QualifiedName%22%20-%3E%20%22ccc1_c%22%0A%0A%7D), which corresponds to the following AST:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used this but it gives me an error for for single SimpleType (e.g., `int`). It parsed qualified names, but It doesn't build the expected parse tree (e.g., `foo.boo` is a single `CommonTree`).